# Request Website Timeout While Trying To Read Website- Python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I am attempting to read and parse a website that returns a JSON. Every attempt I have made, it gives me a timeout error or not an error at all(I have to stop it)

URL:

```
https://api.louisvuitton.com/api/eng-us/catalog/availability/M57089
```

Code I have tried:

```
import requests
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

#Trial 1
BASE_URL = 'https://api.louisvuitton.com/api/eng-us/catalog/availability/M57089'

headers = {
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36'
}


response = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers)

#Trial2
url = ('https://api.louisvuitton.com/api/eng-us/catalog/availability/M57089')
    req = Request(url, headers= headers)

    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
    page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")
    obj=json.loads(str(page_soup))

#Trial3

import dload
j = dload.json('https://api.louisvuitton.com/api/eng-us/catalog/availability/M57089')
print(j)
```

So far none of these attempts or any variation similar to these have been successful to open the website and read it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you make a request, are you using some sort of authentication? It looks like the example URL returns an "Access Denied" message otherwise. I don't recommend posting the authentication in your question, but just checking. If no authentication is being used, I wonder if that relates to your issue?

Comment: Nope, no authentication. That has happened to me before, I just use a vpn or hotspot from my phone and it goes away.

Comment: Probably you have been querying them a lot and they have blocked your primary IP address.